# Positioning 100% width div at the bottom of a fixed width float

Tags: css, html

I know this kind of question get asked everyday, but I don't seem to find a solution to this particular one...

So, the idea is pretty simple, I want to create a 3 column fixed width layout, with 100% width header and footer.

Everything seems to work aside from the footer.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xMQLy/1/

So essentially the problem seems to be that, because the main body + lateral columns does not have a fixed height, the footer is not positioned at their bottom.

How would I go fixing that?

thanks

Comment: Your CSS appears to be incomplete. It abruptly ends at `.rightcol`.

Comment: @thirtydot: you probably clicked during those 30sec it took me to realize I did not save the final version :) Now it works

Comment: You shouldn't be using `position: absolute` so much.

Comment: @thirtydot: please feel free to provide a solution without it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `absolute` or `fixed` for the `position` CSS property rips an element from the context of the parent. So, the parent width/height won't be affected by this child's size. The `float` properties also have this effect: It's not possible to effectively style using `position:absolute/fixed` or `float`.

I've thrown away these properties, and revised your code: @**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/xMQLy/5/

Some changes:

- Thrown away useless CSS properties:
  <strike>`.wrapper{position:relative;top:0}`

  `` `.leftcol and .rightcol {floar:right/left} ``</strike>
- Grouped together common styles (`.leftcol, .main, .rightcol`).
- Updated HTML source, added a `<div class="wrapper-align">` wrapper around each div in the source, and **removed** whitespace between these wrappers <sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>[1]</sup>
The `.leftcol, .main, .rightcol` elements can be positioned next to each other applying `display:inline-block` on each div. However, the default alignment for these elements is the bottom. Because the columns have to be located at the top, `vertical-align:top` has to be used. This CSS property can only be used at **inline elements**. To achieve this layout without messing with `float` or `display:absolute/fixed`, an `inline` wrapper around a `display-block` element is necessary.

The whitespaces have to be removed, to prevent creating a gap between the elements. To illustrate, compare these pages: [No whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/xMQLy/5/) vs [White space](http://jsfiddle.net/xMQLy/6/).

Comment: +1 although it does not work if the columns are longer then the main content.

Comment: you're right about the floats... leftovers from previous trials

Comment: Working on that atm. I'm getting rid of all `position:absolute` properties.

Comment: thanks, if you could make it without absolute it would be great. I've been trying that all morning and it's really driving me mad...

Comment: The JSFiddle has invalid HTML. Block elements are not allowed within inline ones. Your example has a `<div/>` within a `<span/>`.

Comment: Wow! That looks very promising! I had to change `wrapper-align` to inline-block too, in order for it to work in Chrome and Safari and, obviously IE6 and IE7 don't like it... I have to see if I can safely adapt it to the real website now.

Comment: `inline-block` is also an inline element, so `vertical-align:top` won't be broken. According to the W3c validator, this lay-out is fully HTML5 valid.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you had to move the left column before the body... I think that will not be great for me, anyway thanks for the pointers I'll continue working on it.

Comment: @nico, even from a semantic point of view, having the left column at the right makes sense. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @RobW: nothing, I solved the problem. I just want the main content of the page before the content of the columns, that's all. Anyway I ended up using floats + inline-block which works fine (aside from IE6/7)

Comment: When the columns have a greater height than `.main`, they will overlap the footer, FYI.